How to change fontsize of a plot generated with a function from a package?
this might be a niche question, but I'm using a special function from the package diffracsim to create a plot. Namely this function. Is there any way to change the fontsize of the created plot in post process ? I'm trying and trying, but it doesn't seem possible without editing the package itself.

I understand your frustration! Sometimes, changing the font size of plots generated by specific functions in a package can be tricky. However, you can often modify the plot after it's been created using Matplotlib's customization options.
Here's a general approach to change the font size of labels, titles, and ticks in a plot:
*
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    # Assuming 'fig' is the figure object returned by the diffracsim function
    fig = plt.figure()
    # Change the font size of labels, title, and ticks
    fig.axes[0].tick_params(labelsize=14)  # Change tick label size
    fig.axes[0].set_xlabel('X-axis', fontsize=16)  # Change x-axis label size
    fig.axes[0].set_ylabel('Y-axis', fontsize=16)  # Change y-axis label size
    fig.axes[0].set_title('Title', fontsize=18)  # Change title size
    plt.show()




If diffracsim doesn't return a figure object, you might need to access the plot elements directly using plt.gcf() (get current figure) or plt.gca() (get current axes).

Thanks for understanding and proposing solutions ! I'll try to put them into practice ;)
